# StandardScaling ruins the test data score for my linear regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

When I apply StandardScaler to my train data after traintestsplit, the score for the train data is ok but the score for my test data makes no sense.

I tried LinearRegression(normalize=True) and it also made the score of my test data go crazy.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

ss = StandardScaler()
X_train_sc = ss.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_sc = ss.transform(X_test)

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train_sc, y_train)

print(lr.score(X_train_sc, y_train))
print(lr.score(X_test_sc, y_test))
```

Results are:

0.961269156232134

-1.5466488732709964e+19

Why??? Please, help!

Note: If I do not run the StandardScaler, then both my scores make perfect sense.

Comment: Where does `StandardScaler` come from?

Comment: Sorry! 
`from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler`

Comment: I agree that this is strange. How big is the dataset? Does changing the random seed change the situation?

Comment: Changing the random seed changes the number to an equally absurd number (for example: -9.27664884858383e+20) and the size of the dataset is (2051, 384).

Comment: Try `lr.predict(X_test_sc)` and then evaluate it with `y_test` using MSE and MAE methods. This way we will be able to find the problem.

Comment: MSE is 5.587279895513755e+28

MAE is 11600880782015.844